# Can you create a custom attribute in c# with "hidden" properties?

Tags: c#

Normally when you create a custom Attribute class, any public property with a getter and a setter is automatically exposed to the person applying the attribute on the class, so that the person using the attribute can specify the value of that property.

I want a custom attribute class which exposes a getter and setter for a particular property, but which **does not** allow this property to be specified as a named argument to the attribute on creation.  Example:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool MyProperty
    {
        get { /* do something */ }
        set { /* do something */ }
    }
}


// The following line should be a compiler error, MyProperty should
// be hidden for attribute initialization!
[MyCustomAttribute(MyProperty=true)]
class MyClass
{
};
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: No way. If it's public you can set it.

Comment: Why not make the property `internal`?

Comment: Why would you want to do that anyway? Tell us your use case, perhaps we can suggest another solution.

Comment: You could replace the property with a getter and a setter method.

Comment: What is the point of a property *setter* on an attribute that isn't set in the declaration?

Comment: This seems like a very very odd thing to do.  You want to have a setter, but don't want the setter accessible when the attribute is being used? huh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply make the property (or just the property setter) [`internal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), if you intend to use it elsewhere in your code, but don't want others to see it.

Alternatively, if you want to expose the property other users, but just disallow setting it in the declarative syntax, you could not expose a property setter, but provide a different method to set the value if you need to:

```
class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool MyProperty
    {
        get { /* do something */ }
    }

    public void SetMyProperty(bool value)
    {
        /* do something */
    }
}
```

Comment: Might also use an `internal set;' in the property declaration.

Comment: Thanks, I've done something similar.  Exposed a public property with a getter and setter, but made only the setter internal.  i think this is sufficient for what I need.

Answer (score 1):

If the property is public, there is no way of preventing it from being assigned when the attribute is applied. As suggested by dtb in the comments, you could use getter and setter methods instead, but that probably wouldn't help you...

Attributes are not made to be modified at runtime. When you retrieve the attributes from a class or member (or anything else) using reflection, you only get copies of these attributes, so even if you modified them, the next time you would retrieve them, you would get a fresh, unmodified copy.

Comment: That's true, but my application is performance intensive, and I need to use the attributes in a tight loop and profiling has indicated that using reflection to get the custom attributes is a huge bottleneck.

As such, I've resorted to caching an initial copy of the attribute structure and only referring to the cached copy, so the copying wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @ZacharyTurner, OK, but in that case, why not use another type (not an attribute) to cache the data? That would be much cleaner IMO...

Comment: I guess that's not a bad idea, I might consider that.